# Trying to validate one or more email extensions using regular expression

Tags: regex, forms, validation, expression, preg-match

I'm getting a user to input their email address and trying to validate it using regular expressions and the preg match function. I'm unable to get the code to validate different email extensions (hotmail, gmail, blueyonder etc.) as I'm only able to get it to accept one and cannot use an OR function in the code. I'm not getting a specific error but as it is the user will have to be limted to just using the 'gmail.co.uk' extension. Any help?

Code:

```
<?php
$emailErr = "";
$email = "";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

if(empty($_POST["email"])) {
$emailErr = "Email is required";
}else{
$email = ($_POST["email"]);

if (!preg_match("/[a-zA-Z_-]+@[gmail]+.+[co]+.+[uk]/",$email)){
$emailErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";

}
}
}

?>
<html>

<head>

<title> symbol test</title>

<style>

.error {color: #FF0000;}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<form name = "testform" method="POST">

<p>Email:<input type="text" name="email" style="width:20%"/>
<span class="error">*<?php echo $emailErr;?></span>

    <p><br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/></br></p> 

</form>

   <?php

 echo $email;

 ?>
 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`[gmail]` is not the actual way to go. This matches g or m or a or i or l.

```
[a-zA-Z_-]+@gmail\.co\.\uk
```

Add anchors if necessary.

```
if (!preg_match("~^[a-zA-Z_-]+@gmail\.co\.uk$~",$email)){
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a generic regex to match all kind of valid email-ID then you can try

```
^(?![\W_])((?:([\w-]{2,})\.?){1,})(?<![\W_])@(?![\W_])(?=[\w.-]{5,})(?=.+\..+)(?1)(?<![\W_])$
```

Look at the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aR4hJ0/1) for detailed overview.